# HTML display issue in apps script : Placeholder color not working

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I have created this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9dp24zgr/ and it works exactly as intended, but in the Google-Apps-Script where it actually lives the placeholders are still pale grey and creating a problem with some of my colleagues. Why is the Google version not responding and what can I do to rectify this?

The code I added is:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: rgba(9,9,9,.9);

}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(9,9,9,.9);

}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(9,9,9,.9);

}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: rgba(9,9,9,.9);

}
```

which came from the site [CSS3 Placeholder PseudoElements](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-css3-placeholder-pseudo-element)

[image: screen grab of actual Google version]

Update
    [Gadget in a site](https://sites.google.com/site/scripttest2015/)
    [Google-Script](https://script.google.com/macros/d/MedoQOtHcUuyDV7D_iYX89e0fLL19UkVS/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvEhJSOZqwj8BgF4EvBltfiG0Fed_Zfu5yuT9rFZVAwItyzXZBz9k9Ix8EttHlvil7_AQ5nv_I41aGnjjFIk0m2Wr4H2U4YVLZdNt6nPstv4Ujpw7mEoMGndEJAEo0MZYPkHlYo2gT8)
    [Google-Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gLxxsC-IDeB7VYecMJssePDuijSYJdUuoamsUCmw9ho/edit#gid=0)

Update, I have tried adding in the lines `opacity: 0.9;` in the CSS and the color code in hex with `color: #000000;` and these make no difference in the output either.  I have also tried changing the code for the class controlling the text boxes too with:

```
  .vdcComment {
  background: #FFF;
  width:300px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: 9 is not a valud value for `alpha`...did you mean 1 or .9?

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse @Paulie_D. Didn't realise I had done that and yes I did mean .9 I have changed the code to that and the JSFiddle does exactly as intended, but the Google Apps version still does not respond and it showing the font in pale grey.

Comment: You will need to show us the Google Apps version for debugging.

Comment: @ManojKumar I have added links to the question

Comment: also are you using htmlService iframe mode?

Comment: Not sure I understand that @ZigMandel. Can you explain?

Comment: make sure to google "htmlservice iframe mode" so you know what it means first.

Comment: Thanks @ZigMandel, I didn't understand the page in its entirety tbh, but I have changed the line `.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);` to `.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);` and it does work as I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: I suspected that but you didnt have enough info in the question to make sure. ive added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are likely not using the IFRAME sandbox mode, thus running into "caja" issues.

use `.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);` and it should work.

read here about the different script modes and their restrictions:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions